# Pushing Objects Into Array repeats last entry

Tags: typescript

I have a quite complex object which I have to fill partly with data coming from an API.

Lets asume my object looks like this

```
{
   attribute1: number, 
   attribute2: number, 
   static1: number,
   static2: number,
}
```

I have a function that return a Object with set static values.

Now i have to fill the other attributes with the API response.

My try:

```
private pretifyApiResponse(apiResponse) {
const template = this.getTemplate();

console.log(template); // {attribute1: 0, attribute2: 0, static1: 123, static2: 456}

const result: myInterface[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < apiResponse.length; i++) {
   template.attribute1 = apiResponse[i].attribute1 || 0;
   template.attribute2 = apiResponse[i].attribute2 || 0;

   console.log(i+'. Template'); 
   console.log(template);
   result.push(template);
}

console.log('Final Result')
console.log(result);
```

The thing is now, inside of my loop the results are correct and also the template is.

But after the loop the array contains only the last entry, but x times.

Here the logs of my function above
[image: Consele logs of my function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bypass the reference and create a copy I found a somehow questionable method.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(template));
```

It works though, but it feels kinda hacky.

I was trying to use `Object.assign()`, but I ran into the same problem.

A *real* solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you are referring to same object so if you change in one it will affect on others.

```
private pretifyApiResponse(apiResponse) {
console.log(template); // {attribute1: 0, attribute2: 0, static1: 123, static2: 456}

const result: myInterface[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < apiResponse.length; i++) {
    const template = {};
    const temp = Object.assign(template, template);
   temp.attribute1 = apiResponse[i].attribute1 || 0;
   temp.attribute2 = apiResponse[i].attribute2 || 0;
   console.log(temp);
   result.push(temp);
}

console.log('Final Result')
console.log(result);
```